# Django JsonField Lookup Filtering with an unknown subkey

Tags: django, django-models, filtering, lookup

I want to filter a Django model by the value of a nested JSON field key when I don't know one of the key values.

E.g. I want to do:

```
Model.objects.filter(json_field__firstKey__{UNKNOWN_ID_KEY}__desiredKey__in=[OPTION1,OPTION2])
```

so that whenever this nested structure exists, and `desiredKey` exists, I can filter by the desiredValue being `OPTION1` or `OPTION2` i.e. `{desiredKey: OPTION1}` or `{desiredKey: OPTION2}`.

I have not managed to find documentation supporting this.

Is this possible?

If not, does anybody have any alternavtive suggestions?

Answer (score -2):

filter_dict = {'json_field__firstKey__' + UNKNOWN_ID_KEY + '__desiredKey__in': search_string}

.filter(**filter_dict)

Make a dict with the key as your query as a string, and the value as the array then use ** before the call in .filter() to unpack it.